# What is the point of using Storyboard as timer?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, timer, storyboard

I've seen some examples of code where StoryBoard is used as Timer, such as:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (_sb == null)
        {
            _sb = new Storyboard();
            _sb.Completed += _sb_Completed;
            _sb.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
        if (_sb_completed)
        {
            _sb.Begin();
            _sb_completed = false;
        }
    }
    void _sb_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PerformUpdate();
        _sb_completed = true;
    }
```

Is Storyboard at some point better than Timer? Why do people use it?

P.S. Question is related to Silverlight and/or WPF.

Comment: do you see this often? seems odd to me, perhaps this is just of those things where the developer doesnt know about the DispatcherTimer or something?

Comment: Using storyboard as a timer is holdover from the SL2 times. Shouldn't be any reasons to use it now in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Storyboard, like a DispatcherTimer, runs on the UI thread. So in either case you will never see a cross thread exception.

You can use a Storyboard over a DispatcherTimer because the Storyboard has a higher priority.

But im not sure about the Timer object itself as I've never really used it in favor of the Storyboard or DispatcherTimer.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `Storyboard` is different from using a standard `System.Threading.Timer`.  The `Storybroad` operates on the main thread hence the `Completed` even can manipulate the UI elements without getting cross thread exceptions.  The standard `Timer` callback doesn't run on the UI thread and will therefore need additional help to manipulate UI elements.

However as Mark points out if all that is really needed is a delay then a `DispatcherTimer` would be the more intuative choice.  The difference with `DispatcherTimer` is that its designed to invoke its `Tick` event regularly whereas the `Storyboard` will only call `Completed` at most once for each call to `Begin`.  A `DispatcherTimer` can be used in this way by calling its `Stop` method in the first `Tick` event occurance.