# wpf is it possible to block ui thread while animating?

Tags: wpf, animation, serialization, synchronization

folks, I came across a problem when I was going to show off for my daughter the power of WPF animation on resolving Hanoi problem. The problem related codes are below:

```
   void MoveSet(Disk[] disks, int maxIndex, char from, char via, char to)
   {
        if (maxIndex > 0) MoveSet(disks, maxIndex - 1, from, to, via);
        MoveOne(disks[maxIndex], from, to);
        if (maxIndex > 0) MoveSet(disks, maxIndex - 1, via, from, to);
   }
```

The above codes move disks recursively. And I added animation in MoveOne method  like this:

```
void MoveOne(Disk disk, char from, char to)
{
    // set animation parameters
    ... upAnimation...
    ... levelShiftAnimation...
    ... downAnimation...

    Storyboard.SetTarget(upAnimation, disk);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(levelShiftAnimation, disk);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(downAnimation, disk);
    storyboard.Begin(disk);
}
```

The above codes work good. But all animations run almost at the same time. After a few unordered animations all disks changed position. It looks not cool. So I want to show the animation of each disk one by one. I modified the MoveOne  method and made such changes:

```
void MoveOne(Disk disk, char from, char to)
{
    ...
    Storyboard.SetTarget(upAnimation, disk);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(levelShiftAnimation, disk);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(downAnimation, disk);

    AutoResetEvent signaler=new AutoResetEvent(false);
    EventHandler eh = null;
    eh = (s, e) => 
    {
        storyboard.Completed -= eh;
        signaler.Set();
    };
    storyboard.Completed+=eh;
    storyboard.Begin(disk);
    signaler.WaitOne();
}
```

The above modifications made the whole program stuck. I think the cause is that both animation and MoveOne method are running in the only one UI thread, blocking MoveOne method blocks also the animation. So I tried to create and start(using UI dispatcher to invoke) animation in another newly created task, it didn't work yet. 
At last, I had straighten up my real demands. I want to run one animation and  block other animations and all of them run on the same sole UI thread. It seems to be contradictory.
I don't know whether I have a wrong understanding. And, is there any solution for this occasion?

Comment: Try use key frame animation.and use non-overlapped KeyTime in each frame. See this MSDN link for examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742524%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the execution of the storboard in a Task and `await` that task.

This could look as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14695474/1384848). Basically, you subscribe to the `Completed` event of the `Storyboard`. Then you can easily await the result. (code slightly adopted from the provided link).

```
public static class StoryboardExtensions
{
    public static Task BeginAsync(this Storyboard storyboard, FrameworkContentElement element)
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        if (storyboard == null)
            tcs.SetException(new ArgumentNullException());
        else
        {
            EventHandler onComplete = null;
            onComplete = (s, e) => {
                storyboard.Completed -= onComplete; 
                tcs.SetResult(true); 
            };
            storyboard.Completed += onComplete;
            storyboard.Begin(element);
        }
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

In your case, all you need to do is, replace the call of `storyboard.Begin(disc);` in your `MoveOn`-method with `await storyboard.BeginAsync(disc);`.

With this change, you turn an event-based approach (using the `Completed` event) into an awaitable task which makes the handling much easier.